# Fabric icon disabled in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-fabric

I'm not able to access fabric from the android studio. The plugin is installed but the icon seems disabled. Here is the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Version of Android Studio and fabric plugin ?

Comment: Android Studio 3.0.1 and for fabric I just install plugin from settings

Comment: Fabric plugin 4.1.1

Comment: Restart Android Studio, Is it on Windows of MacOSX.

Comment: Windows I reinstall android studio but same issue.

Comment: Finally, I solved this by clearing fabric cache from gradle.

Comment: great, that was unusual problem, post your solution as an answer and accept so that it'll help others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by clearing Gradle cache and all fabric files from the system and reinstalled plugin in the Android studio, that helped me.

Comment: Find fabric files using "Search Everything" software and remove all files completely from your system.

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me:

1. Uninstall the Fabric plugin and restart Android Studio.
2. Then delete the .crashlytics folder located here:

   - On Windows: %USER_HOME%/.crashlytics
   - On Mac/Unix: $HOME/.crashlytics
3. Finally, reinstall the Fabric plugin and restart Android Studio again.

Comment: Similar issue happened to me, I just did this in my Windows machine and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: For ubuntu users also, it works same as ios(home -> .crashlytics), go to view->show hidden files, and there you go.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it by menu View -> Tool Windows -> Fabric

Comment: no there is no option for fabric. Even i can see icon but i couldn't access it.

Comment: Not Able see any option there.